# Refresh page after FileWatcher event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the FileSystemWatcher in my asp net mvc application. It detects .txt files when they changed. I should show these changes on view page. But i can not understand how it does. Because how i call page refresh from FileSystemWatcher? Or i must write setTimeOut js function on the client side? Here is the code:

```
public class FileWatcher
{
    //private int readLinesCount = 0;
    private string watchedPath;

    public FileWatcher(string watchedPath)
    {
        this.watchedPath = watchedPath;
        InitFileSystemWatcher();
    }

    private void InitFileSystemWatcher()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher oFileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

        //Set the path that you want to monitor.
        oFileWatcher.Path = watchedPath;

        //Set the Filter Expression.
        oFileWatcher.Filter = "*.txt";

        oFileWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileSystemWatcherUpdated);

        oFileWatcher.Error += Watcher_Error;

        oFileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void Watcher_Error(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        // Watcher crashed. Re-init.
        InitFileSystemWatcher();
    }

    void FileSystemWatcherUpdated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        //A file has been changed in the monitor directory.
        try
        {
            RecordEntry(e.Name);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            InitFileSystemWatcher();
        }
    }

    private void RecordEntry(string fileName)
    {
        BLogic bll = new BLogic();
        bll.AddParamsByFileWatcher(fileName);
    }
}
```

And it is a BLogic's method:

```
public void AddParamsByFileWatcher(string fileName)
{
    if (fileName != null)
    {
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();
        controller.Server.TransferRequest("/Home/Monitoring", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use something like Websockets or SignalR to update your view without polling the server for updates.

Comment: thisextendsthat, But is there another way to do that? Because my application has not got a chat or other services. I need only refresh the web page like RedirectToAction("/Home/Monitoring") IF THIS PAGE IS OPENED IN CLIENT'S BROWSER

Comment: I think your options are either what I suggested or to periodically make ajax calls to update the view with JS like you suggest in your question. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484501/pushing-data-from-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-to-a-view

Comment: Your suggestion is as a little efficient solution:) but some of my "advisers" said me that too many regular ajax queries would overload the server and page refresh is need in rare situations :(

Comment: Is it mean that this problem is the hardest for stackoverflow's masters and gurus?

Comment: @LifanSolano it's not hard problem, but because of the way internet works, you have only two solutions. Either using websockets or periodical ajax calls (aka long pooling). There is no other way to send data from server to client.

Comment: I understood all of those points of view